# How to create a complex tablelayout like in the img?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to find a way to implement following table in xml, however i couldn't manage to do it yet. If anyone have any points, they will be very appreciated.

[image]

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be able to help you, here is the code for the basic screen,it might not be perfect but make some changes and it will come good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:text="Place of the Item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
     <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:text="Measure Taken"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView 
                android:text="Port"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                />
             <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="CL"
                />
             <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="StarBoard"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    />
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now for the List view ,you will need a custom list adapter ,im sure you know how to do it.
The list xml code will be something like this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
        android:text="Firstitem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
   <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
 <TextView 
        android:text="Seconditem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <TextView 
                android:text="thirditem"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                />
             <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4thitem"
                />
             <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5thitem"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I seriously hope this helps. For table format always go Linear Layout screens.
Feel free to make changes everyone.

Comment: Dear Ashwin, I will check it and get back to you. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I check your code, and it seems like it can be done by following your approach. Only thing I will have to deal is listview in here, because I am wrapping everything up inside a scroll layout, since I have lots of other layout items in the current screen. And inside a scroll layout, it will be difficult to manage stuff for a listview, at least needs some hacks from my other experiences. I will probably use directly linear / relative layout configuration for listview side.